# Filter if request.get() is parameter is not set

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter

I'm trying to do simple django filter.

Here is my code line which do filtering:

```
cars = models.CarForRent.objects.filter(car_in_city=request.GET.get('city')).filter(travel_abroad=request.GET.get('travel_abroad'))
```

Now it only works if all parameters is set. If I submit blank request.GET.get('city') or blank request.GET.get('travel_abroad') parameter it returns none.

How to make if request.GET.get('city') is empty to return all items in all cities?

Ofcourse I could write if's for each get parameter but it must be easer way.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you could improve your code readability by importing model you are filtering:

```
from models import CarForRent
```

If you are doing manual filtering you'll have to use ifs.

```
city = request.GET.get('city')
travel_abroad=request.GET.get('travel_abroad')
cars = CarForRent.objects.all()

if city:
    cars = cars.filter(car_in_city=city)
if travel_abroad:
    cars = cars.filter(travel_abroad=travel_abroad)
```

Alternative is to use something like https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter which allows blank parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you had many fields, then it might be worth doing the filtering in a loop:

```
cars = models.CarForRent.objects.all()
for fieldname in ['city', 'travel_abroad', ...]:
    if request.GET.get('fieldname'):
        cars = cars.filter(**{fieldname: request.GET[fieldname]})
```

If you only have a couple of fields, then a couple of if statements is probably easiest.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, [the `Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) may be useful in this case for filtering.

```
from django.db.models import Q

city = request.GET.get('city')
travel = request.GET.get('travel_abroad')

q = Q()
if city:
    q &= Q(car_in_city=city)
if travel:
    q &= Q(travel_abroad=travel)

qryset = CarForRent.objects.filter(q)
```

you can also use OR operation instead of AND.